# Pegar cor dinamicamente

Tags: android, kotlin

Criei algumas cores no arquivo `colors.xml`

```
<color name="colorBackground1">#5c6bc0</color>
<color name="colorBackground2">#1e88e5  </color>
<color name="colorBackground3">#00838F</color>
```

No `adapter` quero setar a cor dinamicamente

```
val cor = "R.color." + cores.get(position)
val colorValue = getColor(context, cor)
vh.item.setBackgroundColor(colorValue)
```

A variável `cores`contém somente o nome da cor, exemplo `colorBackground1`.
Mas na linha
 `val colorValue = getColor(context, cor)`

ele não aceita a variável `cor`, esperando um `int` mas tá passando uma `string` e não achei um jeito de converter. A string sai com o nome certo, `R.color.colorBackground1`. Como resolver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ou você pode transformar `val cor = "R.color." + cores.get(position)` em inteiro.

ou o ideal é utilizar o seguinte método:

```
getResources().getIdentifier("name", "resource", "package");
```

No seu caso ficaria então:

```
val cor = getResources().getIdentifier(cores.get(position), "color", getPackageName());
```

Espero ter ajudado.